# Magento 2 and PayPal Pro

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment-gateway, paypal-pro

I am running Magento 2.1.7 and Paypal Pro 2.0. From what I understand from the people at Paypal, Magento 2 runs a $0.00 transaction before it processes the actual payment; apparently, that is proper functionality for Magento 2. I know, it is weird, but I suppose there is a reason. Not a problem, except that PayPal charges me $0.30 for each of these false transactions.

The people at PayPal said that the Magento shopping cart should be modified to add a prefix to the invoice, and that will solve the problem.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're wrong. Yes, PayPal with authorize the user but there won't be a second charge of $0.00.

Comment: But PayPal is charging $0.30 for each $0.00 CC transaction.